# get lead value based on rankings

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get the lead value based on rankings.
Example: for rank #1 (using rank window function), I would need the value of a certain column for rank#2. My problem is, if there's a tie in rank#1 (like 2 rows tied at rank#1) the prior value that i'm getting for row#1 is correct (column value of rank#3) while the prior value on row#2 is getting null.

```
sample data
rankings, employee, col_date,     job, col_a, col_a_date
1        john smith  2022-05-12   a    abc    2022-05-12 
1        john smith  2022-05-12   b    def    2022-05-12 
3        john smith  2022-03-27   a    ghi    2022-03-27 
4        john smith  2021-09-21   a    abc    2021-09-21

What I'm getting - actual result
rankings, employee, col_date,     job, col_a, col_a_date, prev_col_a
1        john smith  2022-05-12   a    abc    2022-05-12  ghi
1        john smith  2022-05-12   b    def    2022-05-12  def
3        john smith  2022-03-27   a    ghi    2022-03-27  abc
4        john smith  2021-09-21   a    abc    2021-09-21  <null>


Expected result
rankings, employee, col_date,     job, col_a, col_a_date, prev_col_a
1        john smith  2022-05-12   a    abc    2022-05-12  ghi
1        john smith  2022-05-12   b    def    2022-05-12  ghi
3        john smith  2022-03-27   a    ghi    2022-03-27  abc
4        john smith  2021-09-21   a    abc    2021-09-21  <null>
```

For both rankings #1, i want to get the value of col_a of the next rank which is rank#3.

```
select *, lead(col_a,1) OVER w as prev_col_a
from (select RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY  employee ORDER BY col_a_date DESC) rankings,
      *
      from table
) WINDOW w AS (
        PARTITION BY employee, job
        ORDER BY col_a_date DESC
    )
  order by rankings, col_a_date desc
```

Comment: can you share sample data from the table `table`, related to the output you get/want to achieve? @Chris08

Comment: @lemon the sample data is from column rankings up to col_a_date, the prev_col_a is what i'm trying to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample is too small to verify the query logic. Depending on the real data, below query may not work as expected. But hope this will be helpful for you to approach your problem.

```sql
-- Sample Table
CREATE TEMP TABLE sample (
  employee STRING,
  col_date STRING,
  job STRING,
  col_a STRING,
  col_a_date STRING,
) AS
SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
 ('john smith', '2022-05-12', 'a', 'abc', '2022-05-12'),
 ('john smith', '2022-05-12', 'b', 'def', '2022-05-12'),
 ('john smith', '2022-03-27', 'a', 'ghi', '2022-03-27'),
 ('john smith', '2021-09-21', 'a', 'abc', '2021-09-21')
]);

-- Main Query
SELECT * EXCEPT(dense_rankings), 
       IF(rankings = MAX(rankings) OVER (PARTITION BY employee), NULL, LAST_VALUE(col_a) OVER w) AS prev_col_a 
  FROM (
    SELECT RANK() OVER w rankings, DENSE_RANK() OVER w dense_rankings, *
      FROM sample
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY employee ORDER BY col_a_date DESC)
  )
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY employee ORDER BY dense_rankings RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING)
 ORDER BY rankings, col_a_date DESC
;
```

output:

[image]

Comment: this works, I really appreciate it. although I was able to solve the same using a dense_rank + self join (dense rank value + 1 = dense rank value)